# Nested forEach / wait for nested to complete

Tags: javascript, foreach

This has been asked in many ways, but I couldn't find a corollary.

I have two arrays and I'm trying to compare dates between the two and build a list, adding a class and changing the status when the dates match. I have a feeling forEach isn't the right tool. Here's what I have. I know the outside loop is continuing before the inner loop finishes, but I'm not sure how to fix it. It seems there would be a straightforward way without async/await.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/jcu8m410/)

```
// main event loop
events.forEach(event => {
  let {
    date
  } = event;
  // presaleEvent loop
  presaleEvents.forEach(presaleEvent => {
    let {
      presaleDate
    } = presaleEvent;
    if (presaleDate === date) {
      status = 'PRESALE EVENT';
      eventClass = 'presale';
    }
  });
// only 3, 5 & 6 should be presale events
  let eventNode = `<li class="event ${eventClass}">${status}</li>`;
  $(eventsList).append(eventNode);
});
```

Comment: Nothing asynchronous is going on there, you shouldn't have to mess with asynchronity

Comment: "*I know the outside loop is continuing before the inner loop finishes*" that's not what happens. What is the problem you observe and what is the expected behaviour? Can you include an [mcve] here to demonstrate what happens?

Comment: the outside loop is not finishing before the inner forEach. The problem is that you set these two variables globally once you find a match.

Comment: @Jhecht ... that was it. I figured it out on my own and then deleted my question, but I figured I should leave it up for someone else.

Comment: glad you got it. scopes are weird. Any reason you're not just setting the value on the event object?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out moments after posting my question (and hours after hitting my head against a wall).

I simply had to reset the vars inside the parent loop but outside the inner loop.

Here's a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/fh56pvr1/).

```
// main event loop
events.forEach(event => {
  let {
    date
  } = event;
  status='EVENT'; // reset the status
  eventClass=''; // reset the eventClass
  // presaleEvent loop
  presaleEvents.forEach(presaleEvent => {
    let {
      presaleDate
    } = presaleEvent;
    if (presaleDate === date) {
      status = 'PRESALE EVENT';
      eventClass = 'presale';
    }
  });
// only 3, 5 & 6 should be presale events
  let eventNode = `<li class="event ${eventClass}">${status}</li>`;
  $(eventsList).append(eventNode);
});
```